# forks from Github API does not match what is shown on the organizer's page

Tags: json, api, github, repository, github-api

I'm trying to do a take home interview assignment here and I ran into 
some problems.

For some reason the forks shown on the Github API: https://api.github.com/orgs/aipub/repos are different than what are being showing on the https://github.com/aipub/ page.

So for example -

python-blogger should have 4 forks.
but on the API json it says 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no forks of `aipub/python-blogger` repository. But it **is**  a fork or the `/theatlantic/python-blogger` among other 3.

```
{
   "fork": true
}
```

However, there are 4 forks of the original repo

https://github.com/theatlantic/python-blogger

And so the API says:

https://api.github.com/orgs/theatlantic/repos

```
{
   "forks_count": 4,
}
```